# Cant locate ADB on Android Studio

Tags: android, adb

I am using android studio, and I want to connect it to my phone, I used to have it, but now it has an erro, and I don't know why this is happening, here is the error:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6XUa.png)

I've already tried to install `adb` through Android Studio and manually, none of them worked
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

1. go to android SDK manager

[image]

2- Copy android sdk Location path

3- Open file explorer and browse to sdk location (past path previously copied )

[image]

4. Navigate to "platform-tools" folder, normally adb.exe should be there but in your case you won't see it probably because your antivirus has quarantined it.

[image]

5. Restore adb from the virus quarantined list and add android-studio folder under exclusions to avoid the issue in future.

Comment: thx for the help, but it didn't work, i don't have an Antivirus so that could not be it, but still, i did what you told and nothing changed, do u have any other sugestion?

Comment: You're welcome, first of all what phone model are you using ? And did you check if you do have adb.exe in platforms-tools or not?

Comment: I am using a Huawei P Smart 2019, and yes i have checked.

Comment: I have Huawei phone and it works just fine side by side with Samsung, what I recommend you is to reinstall Huawei hisuite driver and retry, IN CASE IT DOESN'T WORK then download "SDK platform-tools for windows" from developer.Android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools and copy paste adb.exe, ADBWINApi.dll, ADBWINUSBApi.dll

Answer (score 0):

[Try this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html#Drivers)

Here they have mentioned phone model-wise drivers, download the one which is required (in your case Huawei)

Then go to **Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools Tab** and select the **Google USB Driver** & click OK
[Check this for the same](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb)